# Running Pyomo stochastic example in Spyder

Tags: python, optimization, spyder, pyomo, stochastic

I am aware that Pyomo examples can be run by a command in the Anaconda prompt.

However, I would like to run the stochastic farmer example by using Spyder. I am able to run the deterministic example problem, but not the two-stage (stochastic) scenario example. The files I have are `ReferenceModel.py`, `ScenarioStructure.dat`, `AverageScenario.dat`, `BelowAverageScenario.dat` and `AboveAverageScenario.dat`.

What is the correct script to call these files and to run this two-stage stochastic example in Spyder?

More information about the problem can be found here, but the Spyder script is not given: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modeling_extensions/pysp.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing RootNode.dat file